# Allocator is called once if no default class constructor is passed to std::vector allocator

Tags: c++, vector

Basically I've the following class code:

```
class Foo {

public:
    Foo() { instructions };
    Foo(int a) { instructions };
    Foo(int a, int b) { instructions };

}
```

This one is used as basic type for an std::vector object but, If I assign and init a new vector using the default Foo allocator, the vector is filled up with x different Foo objects. So, the following line:

```
std::vector<Foo> bar = std::vector<Foo>(1337);
```

Produces 1337 different Foo object.

The weird behavior happens when I use the second or third constructor. Indeed, in this case:

```
std::vector<Foo> bar = std::vector<Foo>(1337, Foo(1, 2));
```

`bar` is filled up with the same element. At the end, `bar` is just a vector with 1337 same objects.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The first variant create a vector of `1337` default-constructed `Foo` instances. The second creates a vector with `1337` instances all constructed with the two-argument constructor. Each object is still a different object, but they are constructed the same way. You might want to read e.g. [this `std::vector` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). Also, how do you check if two `Foo` objects are different or the same?

Comment: The second version should call `Foo(1, 2)` once, then make `1337` copies of it using the copy constructor. See constructor #2 at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: I'm not actually checking if the objects are the same but by adding a printf into constructors I noticed that vector<Foo>(10) calls printf 10 times (so the constructor is called 10 different times) and vector<Foo>(10, Foo(1 ,2) calls the ctor only once but what I need is the first behavior for the second constructor

Comment: Try creating a copy-constructor and logging in that. Maybe the vector directly creates only a single object, and then copies it X times instead?